# VB "Index was out of range, must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." When trying to generate a random number more than once

Tags: vb.net, random, indexing

So I'm trying to generate a random number on button click. Now this number needs to be between two numbers that are inside my text file with various other things all separated by the "|" symbol. The number is then put into the text of a textbox which is being created after i run the form. I can get everything to work perfectly once, but as soon as i try to generate a different random number it gives me the error: "Index was out of range, must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." Here is the main code as well as the block that generates the textbox after loading the form. As well as the contents of my text file.

```
Private Sub generate()
    Dim newrandom As New Random
    Try
        Using sr As New StreamReader(itemfile)                      'Create a stream reader object for the file
            'While we have lines to read in
            Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String
                line = sr.ReadLine()                            'Read a line out one at a time
                Dim tmp()
                tmp = Split(line, "|")
                rows(lineNum).buybutton.Text = tmp(1)
                rows(lineNum).buyprice.Text = newrandom.Next(tmp(2), tmp(3))  'Generate the random number between two values
                rows(lineNum).amount.Text = tmp(4)
                rows(lineNum).sellprice.Text = tmp(5)
                rows(lineNum).sellbutton.Text = tmp(1)
                lineNum += 1
                If sr.EndOfStream = True Then
                    sr.Close()
                End If
            Loop

        End Using
    Catch x As Exception                                   ' Report any errors in reading the line of code
        Dim errMsg As String = "Problems: " & x.Message
        MsgBox(errMsg)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rows = New List(Of duplicate)
    For dupnum = 0 To 11
        'There are about 5 more of these above this one but they all have set values,        this is the only troublesome one

        Dim buyprice As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        buyprice = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        buyprice.Width = textbox1.Width
        buyprice.Height = textbox1.Height
        buyprice.Left = textbox1.Left
        buyprice.Top = textbox1.Top + 30 * dupnum
        buyprice.Name = "buypricetxt" + Str(dupnum)
        Me.Controls.Add(buyprice)

        pair = New itemrow
        pair.sellbutton = sellbutton
        pair.amount = amounttxt
        pair.sellprice = sellpricetxt
        pair.buybutton = buybutton
        pair.buyprice = buypricetxt
        rows.Add(pair)
    next
end sub
```

'textfile contents

```
0|Iron Sword|10|30|0|0

1|Steel Sword|20|40|0|0

2|Iron Shield|15|35|0|0

3|Steel Shield|30|50|0|0

4|Bread|5|10|0|0

5|Cloak|15|30|0|0

6|Tent|40|80|0|0

7|Leather Armour|50|70|0|0

8|Horse|100|200|0|0

9|Saddle|50|75|0|0

10|Opium|200|500|0|0

11|House|1000|5000|0|0
```

Not sure what else to add, if you know whats wrong please help :/ thanks

Comment: Do you know at what line the error is generated?

Comment: can you tell us where it happens?  might have to get rid of the Try/Catch to see where it is failing

Comment: Do you need to set `lineNum` back to zero (one) before you call it for the second time? I suspect that's your problem. First call, it is created and set to zero. Then it persists, maybe? I like to declare and initialize variables explicitly for just that reason.

Comment: you are using the LIST like it is an array.  add to a List (your Rows var) by using the `.Add` method.  create a Duplicate object (cant see where that is defined), set the properties then add it to the rows List.

Comment: My best guess: Change all `tmp(n)` to `tmp(n - 1)`. Arrays in vb.net are zero-based. I don't see any `tmp(0)` which is the first item in the array, `tmp(1)` is not.

Comment: it would also pay to check that whatever rows is, has that many things in it

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines to the start of `generate()`:

```
Private Sub generate()
  Dim lineNum
  lineNum = 0
```

This ensures that you don't point to a value of lineNum outside of the collection.

I usually consider it a good idea to add

```
Option Explicit
```

to my code - it forces me to declare my variables, and then I think about their initialization more carefully. It helps me consider their scope, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this little modification.
I took your original Sub and changed a little bit take a try and let us know if it solve the issue

```
Private Sub generate()
    Dim line As String
    Dim lineNum As Integer = 0
    Dim rn As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
    Try
        Using sr As New StreamReader(_path)                      'Create a stream reader object for the file
            'While we have lines to read in
            While sr.Peek > 0

                line = sr.ReadLine() 'Read a line out one at a time

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) And Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) Then
                    Dim tmp()
                    tmp = Split(line, "|")
                    rows(lineNum).buybutton.Text = tmp(1)
                    rows(lineNum).buyprice.Text = rn.Next(CInt(tmp(2)), CInt(tmp(3)))  'Generate the random number between two values
                    rows(lineNum).amount.Text = tmp(4)
                    rows(lineNum).sellprice.Text = tmp(5)
                    rows(lineNum).sellbutton.Text = tmp(1)
                    lineNum += 1
                End If
            End While

        End Using
    Catch x As Exception                                   ' Report any errors in reading the line of code
        Dim errMsg As String = "Problems: " & x.Message
        MsgBox(errMsg)
    End Try
End Sub
```